# Использование lambda для поиска соответствий элементов

Tags: python, list, lambda, set

Дан список `a = [7,4,1]` и дано множество `b = {6,3,9,1}`. Необходимо брать каждый элемент из списка `a` и проверять, есть ли он во множестве `b`. Как только элемент найден, поиск прекратить и добавить этот элемент в список `s`. В данном случае `s` должен включать только 1. Реализовать нужно с использованием lambda-функции.
Без lambda код будет выглядеть так:

```
for x in a:
    if x in b:
        s.append(x)
        break
```

Comment: Я пытаюсь написать что-то вроде этого, но это неверный код.
`b={1, 3, 5}
a=[4, 3, 1]
n=[]
n.append(a)
n.append(b)
s=filter(lambda x: x in n[0] and x in n[1],n)
print(list(s))`

Comment: подсказки: 1 - `next()`, 2 - `filter()`

Comment: @SergFSM, не могли бы вы написать целиком? потому что вариант `s=next(filter(lambda x: x in n[0] and x in n[1],n))`, где n - это список, включающий список `а` и множество `b` , не работает

Comment: `s.append(next(filter(lambda x: x in b, a)))`

Comment: @GrAnd, огромное спасибо за ответ!